# How to replace the value of a part of a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This looks like a question that should've been asked on SO or else where but I just couldn't find it so I'll ask it anyway.

I've got a csv file and it needs to be cleaned. I use `read_csv` to take it into R. Let's call it `df`.

Now column `C` stores human or company names. Most data points are fine, but due to some unimaginable reason, a fraction of them aren't properly decoded(at the time this csv file was generated) and is still being stored in base64 format, which looks like this:`[b64]5b+r5LmQ56aPMjAxMQ==[/b64]`.

I then constructed a function to decode it:

```
MyDecode <- function(x) iconv(rawToChar(caTools::base64decode(x,"raw")),
                              from="utf-8", to = "gb18030")
```

Since `base64decode` is not vectorized, therefore `MyDecode` is not vectorized, and this is what caused me headache when I try to plug it into the `dplyr` pipeline.

First, `mutate` doesn't work because although it returns the whole modified `df` it requires `MyDecode` to be vectorized.

Next, I thought of doing something like `df %>% select(C) %>% filter(grepl("^\\[b64", .[[1]])) %>% sapply(.[[1]], MyDecode)`, but then I have lost all the positional info of the decoded strings.

Finally I went to vectorise `MyDecode` function (although reluctantly). I tried `Vectorize(MyDecode)` but the result is not good. More to the problem, I find out that although printing out warnings, `base64decode` will convert invalid base64 strings(which in my case is the actual names of people and company) to some rubbish anyway so when it is fed to `rawToChar` the original string is ruined. So in order to vectorize it I have to spent much more effort than writing the one-liner core function just to take care of the errors, which led me here to ask this question: is there an `R` way to modify some value by a non-vectorized function in a data frame, and returning the whole modified data frame? 
by saying `R` way I mean not using a for loop to traverse the whole data frame one data point at a time.

It occured to me that maybe `dplyr` isn't the best tool for this kind of task? If true, then perhaps some other packages or even base R would be best suited for it? Or even my mindset of this problem is just misguided?

P.S. I hope to find a more general answer here, because although my specific problem at hand may be hacked in many different ways such as finding a base64 decode function that is actually vectorized or just use a for loop over the specific column `C`, but I believe that more often than not when similar problem emerges the same hack won't work or just become ugly and inefficient.

Thanks!

Edit:

The "ideal" approach that I can think of is something like this: you filter out the part of the data frame you'd like to modify, **with** their "coordinates"(row number, column number) carried along somehow, then use one of the `apply` family function to modify the value in the filtered out data set(thus avoiding to vectorize the function itself), and finally fill them back into the original data frame according to the "coordinates".

Implementation of such idea is much appreciated.

Comment: Use the `Vectorize`d version with `ifelse`, something like `mutate(fixed = ifelse(grepl("^\\[b64", ugly_column)), vectorized_mydecode(ugly_column), ugly_column)`. This will apply the vectorized version of your my_decode function only to the subset of your column that needs it, returning the rest as-is.

Comment: Alternatively, you code put the check for `grepl("^\\[b64", ugly_column)` inside your my_decode function and return the string untouched if false.

Comment: @Gregor I did `MyDecodeV <- Vectorize(MyDecode)`, and the result of `MyDecodeV(df$C)` is that the base64 strings decodes just fine but all the "good" values become `NA`.

Comment: @Gregor I added an if statement at the beginning of `MyDecode` and the now `MyDecodeV` worked in `mutate()` expression, thanks!
Am I correct to say that a function must be properly vectorised in order to work with dplyr verbs?

Comment: Yes? What you're getting at is correct, but I wouldn't put it quite like that---you might be overgeneralizing. Mutate is for adding columns (which are vectors) so whatever expression is inside `mutate` needs to return a vector of the appropriate length. Summarize condenses columns to single rows, so whatever expression is inside `summarize` needs to return something of length one. `select`, `rename`, aren't really vectorized, `filter` expects vectors like `mutate`, but they need to be boolean.

Comment: So, I guess if you replaced "dplyr verbs" with "mutate", I'd agree. Maybe `summarize` too depending how you define "vectorized".

Comment: You are right, that was a rushed conclusion gone wrong.